# Where to Record in Greater Vancouver Area

Tags: field-recording, location

I'm looking for a nice quiet place to do some outdoor recording in the Greater Vancouver Area - obviously the city itself is too loud so I imagine I'd have to take a drive to somewhere quiet.  Are there any other Vancouver sound recordists here with some ideas of where to record?

For example, I'd like to do a bow & arrow session, but I'd prefer to record outdoors if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.

Vancouver is a very noisy place.  I have had some success recording up at the Cypress Bowl parking lot.  You may get some birds in your recordings though if you go at the wrong time (dawn and dusk)  It's a great place to go just as the ski season ends in early March.

As for other areas, it can be really hit or miss.  Due to the lay of the land, there is either a hiway not far away, or you are in one of the many flight paths for air traffic coming and going to YVR.

The airport that Filipe mentioned is Boundary Bay Airport in Ladner.  It's not abandonded, just a low traffic small aircraft airport.  You can find some good areas in Ladner away from the roads, but the air traffic is always a concern it you are trying to record ambiences.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed reply. I actually did manage to get some recording done up at the Cypress parking lot as well; however, got stopped by the local "Rangers" if that's what you'd call them (we were recording motorcycles and they were concerned about the noise disturbing others...)

Answer (score 1):

While i was there, me and a friend found a small abandoned airport, one hour southeast of Vancouver. We drove there after dinner just to record torches, we ended up leaving at 2PM, the place was great!